# SQL Server: divide results of a column based on value from 2 other columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to display a report like this (I plan to do this in SSRS):

[image]

The % is calculated by `BG_SALES/TOTAL_SALES` for the current period and previous period.

How do I go about doing this? Appreciate any help .. thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the first couple of paragraphs in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: So I guess you expect your readers to just "know" that the columns named "TTL_" are the ones you use to calculate total sales? Writing requirements (which is effectively what you are doing here) is difficult - don't make assumptions. Define what you mean. Labels in reports often have very different values from those used in tables. And note that you can do these sorts of calculations in SSRS very easily. The "better" choice depends on your skills, your goals, and your report design.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in two parts. First I would calculate the % you require in SQL

Below I've reproduced your sample data and then returned it with the %'s appended.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Category varchar(10), [Period] varchar(4), [Type] varchar(20), Amount float)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('TTL_SALES', 'CURR', 'CLOTHES', 1234000),
('TTL_SALES', 'PRE', 'CLOTHES', 1355657),
('TTL_SALES', 'CURR', 'ACCESSORIES', 34000),
('TTL_SALES', 'PRE', 'ACCESSORIES', 36000),
('BG_SALES', 'CURR', 'CLOTHES', 550000),
('BG_SALES', 'PRE', 'CLOTHES', 575000),
('BG_SALES', 'CURR', 'ACCESSORIES', 12000),
('BG_SALES', 'PRE', 'ACCESSORIES', 9000)

SELECT * FROM @t
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'BG_%' as Category
    , t.[Period]
    , t.[Type]
    , b.Amount/t.Amount
FROM (SELECT * FROM @t WHERE Category = 'TTL_SALES') t
    JOIN (SELECT * FROM @t WHERE Category = 'BG_SALES') b
        ON t.[Period] = b.[Period] and t.[Type] = b.[Type]
```

This gives us the following results

[image]

I used this query as the dataset query in my report.
I added a matrix with two row groups, one for `Type` and one for `Category`
I added a column group for `Periodd`
I set the [data] cell to `Amount`

I added a blank row within the type group and removed any unnecessary columns.

Finally I reversed the sort order on the row groups so the result came out as expected.

The final design looked like this...

[image]

One more quick change....
I set the `Format` property of the `Amount` textbox to the following...

```
=IIF(Fields!Category.Value = "BG_%", "p2", "n0")
```

This will format the BG_% row as a percentage with 2 decimals and any other rows as numbers with thousand separators and zero decimal places.

The final output looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alan!! I'll try this